# How to order by values in ArrayList in Django?

Tags: django, django-models

I have a model lets say products, which has a field prices that is basically an array:

```
prices = [price on Monday, price on Tuesday, price on Thursday]
```

How do I order products by prices on a specific day, eg: price on Monday?

Comment: Can you share Model?

Comment: I am sorry this is my first question on stack overflow. Nope, I am trying to query the database using something like Products.objects.order_by('prices[1]')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume your `prices` field is an [`ArrayField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#arrayfield) of `DecimalField`.

You can access items like this `prices__0`, `prices__1`, ... (See [index transforms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#index-transforms))

For instance if you want to order by prices according to today's week day:

```py
from datetime import date

weekday = date.today().weekday()
results = Products.objects.all().order_by('prices__{}'.format(weekday))
```

Comment: Absolute Legend!

Answer (score 0):

You can have another  model:

```py
class WeekPrice(...):
   #The day field can be a choice field
   day = models.CharField(....)
   amount = models.DecimalField(..)


class Product(...):
    weekly_prices = models.ManyToManyField(..)
```